# Craft and Plugins are licensed, but I'm still seeing warnings on Production

Tags: license, project.yaml

In my production environment, I have administrative changes disabled, so I see the following messages:

```
* You’re running Craft Pro with a Craft Solo license. Please fix on an environment where administrative changes are allowed.
* 3 plugins have licensing issues. Please fix on an environment where administrative changes are allowed.
```

Fair enough. I logged in to my local environment, and licensed the CMS as well as the plugins. This triggered a change to project.yaml and I can see the addition of the licenses. I then pulled to my production environment, synced changes, and I expected to see these warnings disappear. However, the warnings are still there.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here?

====
UPDATE

Brad's answer below resolves the issue, but there's one additional note. There are many caches in the CMS > Utilities > Clear Caches. The cache that stores licensing is "Data caches".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to clear the Craft `storage/cache` folder on production.

Licensing info is cached for 24 hours at a time.

Comment: This is a good rule of thumb which I completely blanked on yesterday. Thank you sir.